# Couple of Queries on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: ip, private, google-cloud-sql, high-availability

I'm setting up an application which is a set of Mircroservices consuming a Cloud SQL DB in GCP. My queries are  -

1. I want to set up HA for Cloud SQL in across regions(primary region and a secondary region with active replication enabled). I do not see any out of the box set up from Google Cloud to achieve the same. Out of the box HA for Cloud SQL 2nd Gen is to have a HA instance in the same region in another zone in the same region. Please provide the best practice to achieve the same.
2. All the microservices should be using private ip to do actions on this MySQL. How do set this up?
3. Is there any native support from MySQL to enable Active replication to another region?
4. Is it possible to set up manual backup as per customer requirements? I do understand automatic backup available.To meet RPO RTO requirements want to customize db backup frequency - is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to set up HA for Cloud SQL in across regions(primary region and a secondary region with active replication enabled)
```

You can use the [external master](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master) feature to replicate to an instance in another zone.

```
All the microservices should be using private ip to do actions on this MySQL. How do set this up?
```

Instructions for Private IP setup are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip). In short, your services will need to be on the same VPC as the Cloud SQL instances.

```
Is it possible to set up manual backup as per customer requirements?
```

You can configure backups using the [SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/backupRuns).

Answer (score 0):

Please, let me list your questions along with their response:

1. I want to set up HA for Cloud SQL in across regions(primary region and a secondary region with active replication enabled). I do not see any out of the box set up from Google Cloud to achieve the same. Out of the box HA for Cloud SQL 2nd Gen is to have a HA instance in the same region in another zone in the same region. Please provide the best practice to achieve the same.

-According to the documentation [1], the configuration is made up of a primary instance (master) in the primary zone and a failover replica in the secondary zone, at the moment is not possible the HA for Cloud SQL across regions.

2. All the microservices should be using private ip to do actions on this MySQL. How do set this up?

-You can set up a cloud SQL instance to use private IP, please review the next information, you may find it helpful [2].

3. Is there any native support from MySQL to enable Active replication to another region?

-I would recommend to get in contact with mysql support [3], so that you get the help you need, in the meantime you could  review the next link [4], and see if this fits your needs.

4. Is it possible to set up manual backup as per customer requirements? I do understand automatic backup available.To meet RPO RTO requirements want to customize db backup frequency - is that possible?

-You can create a backing up on demand, please review the next link  [5] which helps to illustrate how to set this kind of backups.

Please let me know if this information helps to address your questions.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip

[3] https://www.mysql.com/support/

[4] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-replication-conflict-resolution.html

[5] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backing-up#on-demand

Comment: That's a lot of links! You should try to include the most relevant parts of each link in the answer itself, if possible. This helps prevent your answer from becoming less useful if any of the links stop working for whatever reason.